# Error: MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, http, postman

So, I am following along with Beau in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CqJlxBYj-M&) tutorial over on the freeCodeCamp YouTube learning to build a simple app using the MERN Stack. While using Postman however, I am getting this error message when trying to send a POST request to `localhost:5000/users/add`:

```
"Error: MongoError: not authorized on admin to execute command { insert: \"users\", documents: [[{_id ObjectIdHex(\"5d96cd3f31092833b8253260\")} {username Andrew} {createdAt 2019-10-04 04:40:31.321 +0000 UTC} {updatedAt 2019-10-04 04:40:31.321 +0000 UTC} {__v 0}]], ordered: true, writeConcern: { w: \"majority\" }, lsid: { id: {4 [40 157 203 39 59 227 66 72 188 54 104 29 179 241 37 148]} }, txnNumber: 2.000000, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: 6743803110960922625, signature: { hash: [61 192 72 112 135 6 249 47 34 239 28 238 196 104 30 46 4 217 216 107], keyId: 6741907548619669504.000000 } }, $db: \"admin\" }"
```

I have spent the last couple of hours looking online and at multiple SO Q+A threads but I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem. I see that a common suggestion is to give my user root access in MongoDB Atlas, but I am unsure where I would implement this. I am also using all of the free options, and I have read that since that I am using those options, this error cannot be bypassed?

Here is the current access for the user I created for this project:
[image]

And under Network Access I have selected my own IP Address (using any address did not help).

Here is the code for our **server.js** file:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-idjjd.gcp.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority"; 
mongoose.connect(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!');
});

const exercisesRouter = require('./routes/exercises');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/exercises', exercisesRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`The server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

I have of course changed the username and password for my own in the `uri` variable, just didn't want to enter it here.

And when I run `nodemon server.js`, I see in the terminal:

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting node server.js
The server is running on port 5000
MongoDB database connection established successfully!
```

Here is the code for our **user.model.js** file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema ({
  username: {
    type: String,     
    required: true,   
    unique: true,     
    trim: true,       
    minlength: 3      
  },
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And here is the code for our **users.js** file used for routing:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');

router.route('/').get((request, response) => {
  User.find() 
    .then(users => response.json(users))
    .catch(error => response.status(400).json(`Error: ${error}`))
});

router.route('/add').post((request, response) => {
  const username = request.body.username;
  const newUser = new User({ username });

  newUser.save()
    .then(() => response.json('User added!'))
    .catch(error => response.status(400).json(`Error: ${error}`))
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have followed the tutorial and even compared my code to the code to the completed repo, and I cannot make out any difference, so I am unsure how to to fix this error.

Again in Postman I am selecting `POST`, then entering `localhost:5000/users/add`, and selecting `Body`, then choosing `raw` and `JSON`. I am entering the following:

```
{
    "username": "Andrew"
}
```

If anyone could help me solve this issue it would be much appreciated. Again, this is my first experience using the MERN stack and I really like the idea of using MongoDB alongside Express/React, so I really want to solve this not only for this project, but as well any future projects.

I have also read that examples like mine are lacking the use of bodyParser; however, as mentioned in the video, that is no longer needed and instead we can simply use `express`, as seen in `app.use(express.json());`. Is this correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work! I changed the uri key from:

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-idjjd.gcp.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

to

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-idjjd.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Just swapped out this bit `mongodb.net/admin?` for `mongodb.net/test?` and everything is working!